# Include custom post type single template, but respect theme override of template if it exists

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, template-hierarchy

Through a plugin, I have created a custom post type named "my_custom".

Also through the plugin, I am successfully including a template for the display of a "single" item of my custom post type:

```php
function get_single_custom_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'my_custom' === $post->post_type ) {
            $single_template = PLUGIN_TEMPLATE_DIR . 'default-custom-single.php';
    }

    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_single_custom_template' );
```

This works as expected: my `default-custom-single.php` is displayed for a single entry of "my_custom" post type.

However, *I want to be able to allow themes to override my default*, and create their own template if desired.

How do I check whether there is a pre-existing `custom-single.php` in a theme and ONLY add my plugin-provided template if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`locate_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) first. If this returns anything but an empty string `''` then the template exists either in parent or child theme.

```
if( '' === locate_template( 'custom-single.php' ) ) {
    // Replace given template with your template path.
}
```

Comment: Oooh, nice! Why not just `if( '' === locate_template( 'custom-single.php')` (just curious why we're instantiating a `$located` var?